# Проверьте, пожалуйста, пунктуацию

Tags: пунктуация

Если есть ошибки с пунктуацией, то поясните, пожалуйста.

Предложение:
Проявите же терпение – те, что готовы противоречить!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Проявите же терпение – те, что готовы противоречить!***

1) Синтаксическая конструкция представляется **вполне корректной**, знаки препинания поставлены в соответствии с интонацией. Но проверить решение задачи невозможно без определения  грамматики предложения.

2) Обособленный оборот здесь является **обращением**, но оно выражено нестандартным образом.

Розенталь рассматривает различные **варианты обращений**, выраженных субстантивированными прилагательными, местоимениями, числительными, а также предложно-именными описательными сочетаниями. Например: …Глядите на меня, все! (Дост.) — субстантивированное указательное местоимение;

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126

3) Предложение можно представить в следующем виде: *Проявите же терпение, **готовые противоречить**!*

Здесь ***готовые*** — это субстантивированное прилагательное с предметным значением.

Но в таком виде содержание не прочитывается ясно. Поэтому в значении существительного используется указательное местоимение ***те***, а к нему добавляется **определительное придаточное**.

4) Обособляется такое обращение не запятой, а тире, которое обозначает увеличенную паузу.